# How can I break a hline under a section that is overwriting a wrapfigure?

Tags: sectioning, rules, wrapfigure

The `hline` under section is overwriting the `wrapfigure`. Is there a way to shorten the `hline` only for that section?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%--------------------------------PACKAGES----------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amssymb, marvosym, fontspec, titlesec, xunicode, xltxtra, parskip, phonenumbers, geometry, color, graphicx, wrapfig, hyperref}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

%--------------------------------FORMATTING--------------------------------------%
\addtolength{\voffset}{-.2cm} % Adjust top-margin
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Section formatting
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{0pt} % Section formatting

\definecolor{mdnblue}{rgb}{0.1, 0.1, 0.44}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.95}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{---} % Adjust bullets in \itemize

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner = 1.2cm, % Inner margin
    outer = 2.2cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset = 6mm, % Binding offset
    top = .8cm, % Top margin
    bottom = .3cm, % Bottom margin
}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    urlcolor = mdnblue,
    linkcolor = mdnblue,
}
   
%--------------------------DOCUMENT--------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

%--------------------TITLE-----------------------------------
    
\begin{wrapfigure}[1]{R}{.14\textwidth}
\vspace*{-.6cm}%\hspace*{-.8cm}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=.14\textwidth, cfbox={mdnblue 1pt}, right]{image.png}
\end{wrapfigure} 

{  
    \LARGE \textsc{\color{mdnblue} - } 

    \large - | {\email{-}} | {\phonenumber{-}}
}

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
\section*{Education} \vspace{.7em}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the code could be changed but you need to say what the code is. Most section headings don't use tabular (so rules will not be made with `\hline`) perhaps this is but impossible to tell from an image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True. I added the code

Answer (score 1):

The titlesec package formatting specifies the widths based on `\hsize` and the configured indents. Strangely, while `\section*` forces the width of the title text, ordinary `\section` does not (perhaps that's a bug).

There is a hack to make the rule have the proper width. Change

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
```

to

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\noindent\titlerule\endgraf]
```

but that is too obscure, and it changes the vertical spacing for the worse.

Anyway, for this type of document, I would probably use a full width tabular or two minipages side-by-side rather than wrapfig.

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.85\textwidth}
{  
    \LARGE \textsc{\color{mdnblue} - } 

    \large - | {\email{-}} | {\phonenumber{-}}
}

\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

\section*{Education}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-.6cm}
  \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=\linewidth, cfbox={mdnblue 1pt}, right]{sample-image.png}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{.7em}
```